# Improving access time on SortedDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

I have 2 millions items in a `SortedDictionary<string, MyClass>`

I've done the following and takes ages, any ideas?

```
for(int i = 0; i<dic.Count-1; i++)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(dic.ElementAt(i).Value.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [**`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) class does not directly support (fast) retrieval by index; it is internally implemented as a binary search tree. Consequently, every call to the LINQ `Enumerable.ElementAt` method you've got there creates a new enumerator that iterates each value of the sequence represented by the key-value pairs in the collection (sorted by key) *from the beginning* until it reaches the desired index. This means that the loop is going to have to pull something like `1 + 2 + 3  + ... + Count`  (roughly 2 trillion) elements before it completes, making it (atleast) quadratic in its time-complexity.

Try this instead, which should run in roughly linear time:

```
foreach(var myClass in dic.Values)
   Debug.WriteLine(myClass);
```

If you really do want fast access by index (from the provided code, there doesn't seem to be any reason to indicate this), consider using a [**`SortedList<TKey, TValue>`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) instead. There are downsides to this choice (slower non-appending inserts and deletes) that you should evaluate.

I also notice that the loop condition is `i < dic.Count - 1` rather than the more common `i < dic.Count`. This is either an off-by-one bug, or perhaps you intend to not consider the last value in the dictionary. In the latter case, you could maintain a local variable serving as a counter, or with LINQ:

```
foreach(var myClass in dic.Values.Take(dic.Count - 1))
   Debug.WriteLine(myClass);
```

Answer (score 2):

`foreach` might be faster, since you don't use the indexer

```
foreach (var value in dic.Values)
   Debug.Writeline(value)
```

Also, as far as speed is concerned, `Debug.Writeline` is probably not the best option (what are you going to do with 2 million debug trace entries anyway??). Consider writing to a file, a database, etc.

**EDIT** Looking at reflector, finding a value in a SortedDictionry boils down to a binary search:

```
internal virtual Node<T> FindNode(T item)
{
    int num;
    for (Node<T> node = this.root; node != null; node = (num < 0) ? node.Left : node.Right)
    {
        num = this.comparer.Compare(item, node.Item);
        if (num == 0)
        {
            return node;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The implementation of SortedDictionary's iteration seems a bit more involved:

```
public bool MoveNext()
{
    this.tree.VersionCheck();
    if (this.version != this.tree.version)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion);
    }
    if (this.stack.Count == 0)
    {
        this.current = null;
        return false;
    }
    this.current = this.stack.Pop();
    SortedSet<T>.Node item = this.reverse ? this.current.Left : this.current.Right;
    SortedSet<T>.Node node2 = null;
    SortedSet<T>.Node node3 = null;
    while (item != null)
    {
        node2 = this.reverse ? item.Right : item.Left;
        node3 = this.reverse ? item.Left : item.Right;
        if (this.tree.IsWithinRange(item.Item))
        {
            this.stack.Push(item);
            item = node2;
        }
        else
        {
            if ((node3 == null) || !this.tree.IsWithinRange(node3.Item))
            {
                item = node2;
                continue;
            }
            item = node3;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

It seems to maintain a stack whose top element is the smallest (or largest, depending on the direction) one, and thus always the one to be popped and returned during iteration. I haven't done any complexity analysis, but it's bound to be considerably more efficient than running a binary search each time.

Answer (score 0):

Use `foreach`:

```
    foreach (var pair in d)
        Debug.WriteLine(pair.Value);
```

I bet that debug output takes more time than dictionary lookup though.